# Can I get The URL For An Image I browsed it by Input type field with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, input-field

Can I get The URL For An Image I browsed it by Input type field with JavaScript?

I am Working in a Plugin So I want to get the SRC for the image I browsed it with the input type="file"
so, Is there any Way to return the src ==> as "home/files/icon/..." ?

thanks Alot :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

If the image tag has id attribute, you can get as below.

```
document.getElementById("imgId").src;
```